# Search for a word or a similar word using regex C#

Tags: c#, regex, search

I have text and i want to search for a word or a similar word (fox/foxes). When i set the word in code its work, but when i want to take it from textbox dont work

This work perfectly

```
 var rx = new Regex("fox(es)?", RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

But when i change it with variable dont work and i dont know hot to fix it

```
 var word = textBox2.ToString();
 var rx = new Regex(word+"(es)?", RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

```
var content = @"Foxes are omnivorous mammals belonging to several genera 
of the family Canidae. Foxes have a flattened skull, upright triangular ears, 
a pointed, slightly upturned snout, and a long bushy tail. Foxes live on every 
continent except Antarctica. By far the most common and widespread species of 
fox is the red fox.";

            var word = textBox2.ToString();
            var rx = new Regex(word+"(es)?", RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

            Match match = rx.Match(content);

            while (match.Success)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"{match.Value} at index {match.Index}");
                match = match.NextMatch();
            }
```

Comment: `textBox2.ToString()` doesn't return the text box content. To get the text box content use `textBox2.Text`

Comment: ohh yeah i see it now. I have other question, do u know how to change regex if i want to show me words like foxessm, foxessss when the search word is fox

Comment: Just use the search string `"fox"`? It doesn't even need to be a regex if you don't care about the end of it. `content.Contains(textBox2.Text, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)` should be enough

Comment: @Xerillio yes but when i use contains i dont know how to get word and position, i can take only first and last position

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use IndexOf to find the place of your word:

```
var index = content.IndexOf(textBox2.Text, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
```

if you want to see more occurrences, set a startIndex:

```
//List of all indexes
var indexes = new List<int>();    


int nextIndex = index;

//While it finds new occurrences
while(nextindex != -1)
{
    //adds index to the List
    indexes.Add(nextIndex);

    //searches for new occurrence
    var nextIndex= content.IndexOf(textBox2.Text, indexes.Last() + 1, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);    
}
```

Comment: its work, but i have one last qestion, do u know how to change background color of searched words in text (this is the metod .SelectionBackColor = Color.Yellow;), but i dont know how to use it

Comment: I dont think that it is possible like this, because you are in a single textbox. You have to create multiple textboxes, because you can only change the background color of a whole textbox